# Regular expression for changing spaces to tabs in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to use regular expression in Notepad++ to change spaces to tabs in something like this

> 01 fsdfsd
>
> 01 01 fsdfsd
>
> 01 01* fsdfsd
>
> 01 01 01 fsdfsd
>
> 01 01 01* fsdfsd

How can I keep spaces between numbers and change only the last space?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search for:

```
[ ]([a-zA-Z])
```

(Note that there is a space in front of the character class.) And replace with:

```
\t$1
```

An alternative that might be better suited if you also have lines that are of a different format, or if `fsdfsd` may contain spaces, is this:

```
^((?:\d+\*?)(?:[ ]\d+\*?)*)[ ]
```

Now replace with

```
$1\t
```

This matches any space after the longest possible string of digits with optional asterisks separated by spaces.

Comment: Don't you need a *positive* look ahead? `(?=[a-zA-Z])`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a look head to only match on space followed by something other than a digit, but because notepad doesn't support look arounds, you must resort to a capture-and-release approach looking for a letter:

```
search: " +([a-zA-Z])" (don't include the quotes - there to show the space) 
replace: \t$1
```

Comment: Your corrected soluton is pretty much nothing just copy of solution of m.buettner posted long time before yours

Comment: @Ωmega almost, except mine allows for multiple spaces using the `+`, so it's slightly better IMHO. Incidently, it's a hassle to notify you because we don't have a Greek keyboards